# Multiprocessing find process index?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Let's say we use `multiprocessing.Pool(n)`, is there a ways to find which of the `n` processes we're in?
To illustrate: In the following snippet I'd like to find a way to know what index of the process the `job` function is. I'm not talking about the process number of the system, just a local enumeration of the processes spawned by `Pool`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def job(x):
    process_idx = None # index 1,2,3,4?
    print(f'job {x} process {process_idx}')
with Pool(4) as p:
    p.imap(job, range(10))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find the process index (`1`-based index) by using

```
process_idx = multiprocessing.current_process()._identity[0]
```